# Imagebutton not working

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, imagebutton

I'm making an app including an imagebutton for starting the activity Prov.java.

This app has always been working before, but today I tried activating haptic feedback in xml but then removed it again. Suddenly the button for "Prov.java" didn't work and give me a nullpointerexception. please tell me what to do to solve it!

Imagebutton:

```
<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/a6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/a5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/a5"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/iconprov" />
```

Android manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".Prov"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.felectronix.kyrkeror.PROV" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

main menu:

```
public class Huvudmeny extends Activity {
ImageButton imageButton;
int bak;
int em;
SharedPreferences data;
public static String filename = "bg";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    em = R.drawable.bakgrund;
    data = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
    bak = data.getInt("bakgrund", em);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    RelativeLayout bg = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.might);
    bg.setBackgroundResource(bak);
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    addListenerOnButton();
    addListenerOnButton1();
    addListenerOnButton2();
    addListenerOnButton3();
    addListenerOnButton4();
    addListenerOnButton5();
    addListenerOnButton6();
    addListenerOnButton7();
    addListenerOnButton8();
    addListenerOnButton9();
    addListenerOnButton10();
    addListenerOnButton11();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {

    } else {
        startActivity(new Intent("com.felectronix.kyrkeror.NOINTERNET"));
        finish();
    }
}
```

Main menu onclicklistener:

```
 public void addListenerOnButton9() {

    imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.a6);

    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            startActivity(new Intent("com.felectronix.kyrkeror.PROV"));
            finish();
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: did you `Clean` your project after reverting the changes?

Comment: Clean the project? Since I don't know what it is... probably not :-) will take a look tomorrow. Thx.

Comment: select **Project->Clean** to clean your project

Comment: Unfortunately cleaning the project had no effect. :(

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I tried to apply my background image to the id "might" in the onCreate method of prov.java. This was wrong, and the correct id was "bakgrund". Thank you for your time.

question answered.